# How to access environment variables inside files (.js) under public folder?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to access the config variables in (.js) files that are in public folder. If I try to require the config file as :

```
var config = require('../config');
```

It gives error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Following is the directory structure in the image below :

[image]

Comment: How you are running the application and can you add the directory structure snapshot?

Comment: @SanketPhansekar Added the snapshot of structure.

Comment: are you trying to access from app.js?

Comment: @Sudhakar No, inside public folder we have js folder, in that js file I want to access the config.js

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: is config.js directly placed in public folder?